# How to find all child of a node in a special level ? - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm somewhat new to SQL.

There is a chart like below picture and it was saved into table with `id` , `pid (parent id)` , `level` .

How can I find all child of node in a special level?

For example: All child of `c` in level `4` = `F` , `G` , `H`

[image]

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved by following code:

```
;WITH r as (
     SELECT *
     FROM Chart
     WHERE ParentID = 3

     UNION ALL

     SELECT d.*
     FROM Chart d
        INNER JOIN r 
           ON d.ParentID = r.KID
)
SELECT *
FROM r
where KLevel = 4
```

Comment: This technique uses recursion.  For more on this approach see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to have additional table with node relations. E.g. table `successors` with columns `pid` and `sid` (successor id). There you have rows with pid=3 (C) and sid=4,5,6,7,8. Then you run simple query:

```
SELECT s.sid
  FROM table t JOIN successor s ON t.id=s.pid JOIN table t2 ON t2.id=s.sid
    WHERE t.id=3 AND t2.level=4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query which will look for child rows.
Then you only have to SELECT value with the requiered level.

**Query:**

```
with cte(id) as(
    SELECT id FROM @data WHERE name = @parent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.id FROM @data d
    INNER JOIN cte c ON c.id = d.pid
    WHERE d.[level] <= @level
)
SELECT d.name, d.id, d.pid, d.level FROM @data d
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.id = d.id
WHERE d.[level] = @level
```

**Output:**

```
name    id  pid level
g       7   5   4
h       8   5   4
f       6   4   4
```

**Your data:**

```
Declare @parent char(1) = 'C';
Declare @level int = 4;

Declare @data table(id int, pid int, name char(1), [level] int);

INSERT INTO @data(id, pid, name, [level]) values
    (1, 0, 'a', 1)
    , (2, 1, 'b', 2)
    , (3, 1, 'c', 2)
    , (4, 3, 'd', 3)
    , (5, 3, 'e', 3)
    , (6, 4, 'f', 4)
    , (7, 5, 'g', 4)
    , (8, 5, 'h', 4)
    ;
```